# Find a bound for the summation $\sum_{j=k}^J jc^{k - j - 1} $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, summation

**The problem:**

I've hit what might be a dead-end.  If it is true, I would like to show that for $c \in (0,1)$ and $1 \leq k \leq J$, the sum
$$
\sum_{j=k}^J jc^{1-j-k} 
= 
\sum_{n=1}^{J+1-k} (k-n-1) c^{n}
$$
has an upper bound that is independent of $k$.  I tried the lazy approach of letting $J \to \infty$, but that doesn't seem to work.  Any input here would be appreciated.

**The context:** This is for a PDE course where we are dabbling in functional analysis.  I am trying to show that the spectrum of the right-shift operator on $\ell^2$ is $\{\lambda:|\lambda| \leq 1\}$, and this summation comes from the $|\lambda|>1$ case.  We have not established the notion of an operator norm so I would prefer to avoid using it, though I am well aware it makes quick work of this part of the problem.

Comment: Is $J > k{}{}$?  Is $k > 0$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas yes, $1 \leq k \leq J$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 < c < 1$ then $1/c > 1$, so if $1 \leq k \leq J$ we have

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=k}^J jc^{k - j - 1} &= \sum_{j=k}^J j \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^{1+j-k} \\
&\leq \sum_{j=k}^J j \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^{1+j-1} \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^J j \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^{j}.
\end{align}
$$

The first inequality holds holds because the map $x \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^x$ is increasing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, this doesn't happen to suit my needs since I need my upper bound to be finite as $J \to \infty$, sorry for not having that in the question statement.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, your quantity doesn't have a finite upper bound that holds for all $J,k$ with $1 \leq k \leq J$.  The inequalities in my argument are tantamount to taking $k=1$.

Comment: My apologies!  The sign of the exponent was wrong.  This certainly should change things

Comment: Now take $k = J$ in the new version; it's still unbounded as $J \to \infty$.

Comment: Well, that takes care of that then.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help :)